# Session value expires too quickly in hosting environment.How to fix this in asp.nen

Tags: asp.net

Session value expires too quickly in hosting environment.How to fix this in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do anything about session lifetime**, as even if you change that property in the `web.config` the hosting machine configuration file will always prevail on that, and if they have 5 minutes, no matter if you have 60 minutes in your `web.config` the session live span will always be 5 minutes.

What you can do is change to **[SQL Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)** and it's only there where you have total control on your session live span, but there are advantages and disadvantages on using this.

Or you can avoid the session all together by using the Cache System.

Unfortunaly this happens to much on **Shared hosting**, and **keep in mind** that the session will reset every time your application pool refreshes and this happens much more frequently in shared hosting.

Comment: yes, as I said, use SQL Session, it's the only way you have total control over the session live span, it will be a little slower as it will ask the Database instead the memory, but it will always work. Let me know if you need help setting it up (first follow the link I have given you).

Comment: @balexandre - not true: "The local configuration settings override settings in parent configuration files." source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.ASPx

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout of which your session expires

**Using Web.config**

```
<system.web> 
      <sessionState timeout="20" /> <!-- in minutes -->
</system.web>
```

Comment: I used this .But again Session value lost

Comment: <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="true" timeout="20" >
    </sessionState>

Comment: @Shai no matter what you set, the `machine.config` settings will always prevail and will override anything you put there!

Comment: @balexandre - the other way around: web.config overrides machine.config

Answer (score 0):

**Using IIS**
You can get to the setting by: Open IIS | Properties on Web Site | ASP.NET tab | Edit Configuration... (or Edit Global Configuration to change for more than one site) | State Management tab.
Here you will see a textfield with a label that says "Session timeout (minutes) with a default value of 20 minutes.Edit the value.
For more details visit:
http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html

Comment: I set timeout in web.config file.But again Session value expires.Here is my web.config file

Comment: <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="true" timeout="20" > </sessionState>

Answer (score -3):

add this small javascript in your master page and it will avoid session to expire

```
<script type="text/javascript">
PingAspToKeepSession();
function PingAspToKeepSession() {
var url = "KeppSession.aspx";
var httpOb = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
httpOb.open("POST", url, true);
httpOb.send("");
window.setTimeout("PingAspToKeepSession();", 60000); // every 60 seconds

} 
</script>
```

the page KeppSession.aspx can be an empty page.

Comment: if the application pool resets for some reason, all your session will be erased! this is not true if using SQL Session State!